# printf statement modification in C

Tags: c, printf

Lets take an example: (in C)

consider we have inputted **a,b;** *(say a=1,b=2)*

```
expected output:
    1 + i2
    1 - i2
    1 X i2
```

so i do

```
printf("%d + i%d \n %d - i%d  \n %d X i%d ",a,b,a,b,a,b);
```

Here Iam using **a,b** 3 times in **printf** statement ,the same variable is being defined 3 times

This is a small example so only 3 times we are using *a,b* but in big problems this thing might become a tedious job.

so is their a better way or alternative way to do this ?

Comment: much like in many other cases where you're asked to reduce repetition- the answer is refactoring out your tedious code into a loop.

Comment: I don't think there is. Sometimes programming is a tedious job....

Comment: As @Chase said, the answer is refactoring. For example, you could have a array of strings with each of the formats. Then, for each entry in the array, you print formatted text

Comment: `but in big problems` Could you be more specific? What "big problems" are there? `to do this ?` To print 3 lines? You could type `printf` 3 times. Why is it an issue? Could you give another example?

Comment: @KamilCuk I meant to say like in the above question if i wanted `1+i2`  `1-i2`   `1Xi2`  `1/i2`   `1p+i2`....like this for 10-20 items then things get compilacted like u want to use 

a,b 20 times this becomes  tedious ...

Comment: So the only thing that changes is the char in between? Is it always `%d<something>i%d\n`? Is it a char in between, or a string - how does it change? Ie. step 1. Identify what changes between iterations, step 2. Loop it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use this: (the character array `a` contains `+`,`-` and `X`. The for loop is to display the characters contained in `a`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char a[]="+-X";
  int n1=1;
  int n2=2;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("%d %c i%d\n",n1,a[i],n2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your printf function into few printfs , as it will reduce the work of matching the number of format specifiers and the variables.
By the way , I think you could use a loop structure to reduce that further.